# Unable to authenticate my Spotify credentials with Spotipy API on Raspberry Pi4

Tags: python, oauth, spotify, spotipy

I have a script that scrapes an online radio station for song and updates the playlist every hour. It had been working great on windows but I am unable to set it up my RaspberryPi running Raspbian headless.

Some more information:

1. My Windows machine has the spotify app installed on it while the linux machine doesn't.
2. I have setup the following environment variables: SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID, SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET, SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI.

Here's my code:

```
def authorize():
    scope = 'playlist-modify-public'
    username = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
    token = SpotifyOAuth(scope=scope, username=username, open_browser=False)
    return token

spotifyObject = spotipy.Spotify(auth_manager=authorize())
```

I suspect the problem's got something to do with the Redirect URI. Running the code asks me to enter a url that I am redirected toand I get the following erroe:

```
raise SpotifyOauthError(spotipy.oauth2.SpotifyOauthError: error: invalid_request, error_description: code must be supplied
```

Any help would be appreciated: Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

***There are few ways with the issue with redirect URL :***

> First You should try optimizing your code to get access token and try
> using this for authentication process.

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyOAuth

def authorize():
    scope = 'playlist-modify-public'
    sp_oauth = SpotifyOAuth(scope=scope, open_browser=True)

    # Obtain the access token using the embedded browser
    token_info = sp_oauth.get_cached_token()

    if not token_info:
        # Prompt the user to authenticate and authorize the application
        auth_url = sp_oauth.get_authorize_url()
        print(f"Please visit this URL to authorize the application: {auth_url}")

        # Wait for the user to complete the authentication process
        response = input("Enter the URL you were redirected to: ")
        code = sp_oauth.parse_response_code(response)

        # Exchange the authorization code for a token
        token_info = sp_oauth.get_access_token(code)

    if token_info:
        return token_info['access_token']
    else:
        return None

# Authorize the application and get the access token
access_token = authorize()

# Create a new Spotify object using the access token
spotifyObject = spotipy.Spotify(auth=access_token)
```

**In this updated version, the SpotifyOAuth flow is configured with open_browser=True, which triggers the embedded browser authentication. When the get_cached_token() method is called, it attempts to fetch a previously cached token, if available.**

**Make sure you have the necessary environment variables (SPOTIPY_CLIENT_ID, SPOTIPY_CLIENT_SECRET, SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI) properly set on your Linux machine as you mentioned earlier.**

> Another thing that you can try is to again ensure the URL again,
>
> > For that, you have set in your environment variables (SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI) matches the one registered in your Spotify developer account. The redirect URI should be an exact match, including the scheme (http or https) and any trailing slashes.

> Also you can direct check by using localhost :
>
> > Test with a localhost URI: If you are testing your application locally on the Raspberry Pi, try using a localhost URI as the redirect URI, such as http://localhost:8000/callback. Make sure to update the redirect URI both in your code and in the Spotify developer dashboard.

> Maybe try to check firewall again, there is much possibility that you are facing firewall issue, you can read the error code.

Comment: Tried to use my same old code with a VNC. It redircts me to spotify login page on the browser. After I login for the first time, I can go back to using my code in headless mode.
Thanks for the ellaborate way of authorizing. Will add this to my code.

Comment: Thanks for your support, you can upvote if it would be helpful for you in any case.